# Error when migrate - psycopg2 Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to deploy the local work on the server but i'm having problems with psycopg2 when i run migrate on python manage.py.

SETTINGS:

```
    DATABASES = {
    'default':{
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': '******',
        'USER': '*****',
        'PASSWORD': '**********',
        'HOST': '*******',
        'PORT': '5432'
    }
}
```

MODEL HAVING THE PROBLEM

```
class user(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
   created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
   street = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
   street_num = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
   unit_num = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
   city = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
   postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
   state = models.ForeignKey(state, null=True, blank=True)
   country = models.ForeignKey(country, null=True, blank=True)
   phone = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)

   is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
   .....

class country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=10)


class State(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    short_name = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    group = models.CharField(max_length=2, null=True, blank=True, choices=GROUP_TYPE)
    properties = models.ForeignKey(stateProperties, null=True, blank=True)
```

MIGRATION FILE:
...

```
            ('brand', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=30, null=True)),
            ('exp_month', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=2, null=True)),
            ('exp_year', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=2, null=True)),
            ('country', models.ForeignKey(blank=True, null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='common.country')),
            ('groups', models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, help_text='The groups this user belongs to. A user will get all permissions granted to each of their groups.', related_name='user_set', related_query_name='user', to='auth.Group', verbose_name='groups')),
            ('state', models.ForeignKey(blank=True, null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='common.state')),
```

.....

```
ERROR:
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
  Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK
  Applying profile.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/instantuser/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "common_country" does not exist


**django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "common_country" does not exist**
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Why do you think it's the user model that is causing the issue? Can you also show your country model? Also, are both the models in the same django app?

Comment: @MananMehta hey, because of this: Applying profile.0001_initial . Everything works fine locally using the sqlite dev server. this only happens when im using psycopg2. but im also adding country models

Comment: @AndreMendes Did you try what i suggested in the answer?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. it was a mistake of mine. i had a .gitignore set to ignore migration files and folder. So the migration folder that Country was located was not being send to the master branch.

its fixed. thx for the help.

Comment: Thank you for your self-answer. In my case, it worked very well on the local environment, but when I wanted to deploy on my AWS instance, it always failed but I didn't why. I learned it is important that migrations should be visible to a remote server when I want to deploy a service there.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
country = models.ForeignKey(country, null=True, blank=True)
```

with:

```
country = models.ForeignKey(Country, null=True, blank=True)
```

and that should do it, I believe.

Comment: Sorry, i changed all to lowercase trying to fix this. all my models are lowercase. before all the models were uppercase.

Answer (score -1):

1. Comment **country** model and run

`python manage.py makemigrations app_name`

2. Uncomment **country** model and run the same above command(Country model will be recreated properly)
3. Finally apply the changes to db using migrate:

`python manage.py migrate`